# In which table are images stored in db?

Tags: magento2

For each product I want to know the local image path. I want to make a script and make my own images from an existing installation in my computer.

Is there a way to do it?

For my local development environment I cloned a remote db and I anonymized it. But I also want to replace the images with dummy ones as well. Is there a way to do this? An approach of mine is to:

```
$sql = "SELECT images from img_table";

$pdoConn = new PDO();

$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // create an img here with gd
}
```

DO you know how I can do this?

Comment: Product images are typically stored in the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`table. This table contains the image records associated with each product.

Answer (score 1):

These are following table and path where you can change the image path
in Magento 2, product images are usually stored in database tables with actual file path references.

**The main tables associated with object images are:**

**`catalog_product_entity_varchar`**: This table stores attributes of varchar data type, including image attributes. The `value` column contains the file path of the image.

**`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`**: This table stores information about the media gallery for products, including images, videos, and other media. It contains information about actual image files.

**`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`**: This table associates images with specific products. It associates the product entity ID with the media gallery entry.

**`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`**: This table is used to associate media gallery entries with objects.

Please note that Magento uses a combination of file system storage and database references to manage images. The actual image files are stored in the **`pub/media/catalog/product`** directory.